# arduino graphic display clear display doesn't work

Tags: arduino, display

I am using a Arduino UNO with a c-control programmable graphic display.
I used the documentation of Franzis Maker Kit Grafikdisplays programmieren TURN ON YOUR CREATIVITY .

Display: DXDCG12864-4330  Displaycontroller: ST7564

My code is:

```
#include "TextDisplay.h"

int i=1;
TextDisplay display = TextDisplay();

void setup() {
  display.init(25);
}

void loop() {

char buffer[40];
  display.clear();
  display.println("ABCD");
  sprintf(buffer, "  Dw2: %05d", i);
  display.println(buffer);
  delay(2000);
  i++;
}
```

The problem is that the lines get printed beneath each other and that the display.clear() doesn't clean the display. The display shows after 2 loops:

```
ABCD
Dw2: 1
ABCD
Dw2: 2
```

instant of :

```
ABCD
Dw2: 2
```

TextDisplay.h:

```
#ifndef _TEXTDISPLAY_H_
#define _TEXTDISPLAY_H_

#include "Display.h"

#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif

class TextDisplay {

  public:
    TextDisplay() {};
    void init(byte contrast);
    void println(const char* string);
    void print(const char string);
    void clear(void);
    byte getLastCharPosition(byte line);
    void writeTextBuffer();

  private:
    Display lcd;
    byte textBuffer[8][22];
    byte curserPositionY, curserPositionX;
};

#endif
```

TextDisplay.cpp:

```
#include "TextDisplay.h"
#include "Display.h"
#include "Font.h"

void TextDisplay::init(byte contrast) {
  lcd = Display();
  lcd.init(contrast);
  lcd.clearDisplayRAM();
  lcd.setPageAddress(0);
  lcd.setColumnAddress(0);

  curserPositionY = 0;
  curserPositionX = 0;
  textBuffer[MAX_CHARACTERS_Y][MAX_CHARACTERS_X];
}

void TextDisplay::println(const char* string) {
  int position = 0;
  while (string[position]) {
    char character = string[position];
    print(character);
    string++;
  }
  print(13);
}

void TextDisplay::clear(void) {
  print(255);
}

void TextDisplay::print(char character) {
  switch (character) {

  case 255:
    for (byte y=0; y<MAX_CHARACTERS_Y; y++) {
      for (byte x=0; x<MAX_CHARACTERS_X; x++) {
        textBuffer[y][x] = 0;
      }
    }
    writeTextBuffer();
    curserPositionY = 0;
    curserPositionX = 0;
    break;

  case 127:  //Delete (Putty Backspace)
    if (curserPositionX == 0 && curserPositionY > 0) {
      curserPositionY--;
      curserPositionX = getLastCharPosition(curserPositionY);
      textBuffer[curserPositionY][curserPositionX] = 0; 
    } 
    else if (curserPositionX > 0) {
      curserPositionX--;
      textBuffer[curserPositionY][curserPositionX] = 0;
    } 
    else {
    }
    break;

  case 13:  //CR
    if (curserPositionY < MAX_CHARACTERS_Y-1) {
      curserPositionY++;
      curserPositionX = 0;
    } 
    break;

  default:
    if (curserPositionX < MAX_CHARACTERS_X) {
      textBuffer[curserPositionY][curserPositionX] = character;
      curserPositionX++;
    } 
    else if (curserPositionY < MAX_CHARACTERS_Y-1) {
      curserPositionY++;
      curserPositionX = 0;
      textBuffer[curserPositionY][curserPositionX] = character;
      curserPositionX++;
    }
    break;
  }
  writeTextBuffer();
} 

byte TextDisplay::getLastCharPosition(byte line) {
  for (byte x=0; x<MAX_CHARACTERS_X; x++) {
    if(textBuffer[line][x] == 0) {
      return (x!=0) ? x : 0;
    }
  }
  return MAX_CHARACTERS_X-1;
}

void TextDisplay::writeTextBuffer() {
  for (byte y=0; y<MAX_CHARACTERS_Y; y++) {
    lcd.setPageAddress(y);
    lcd.setColumnAddress(0);
    for (byte x=0; x<MAX_CHARACTERS_X; x++) {
      int position = textBuffer[y][x] * CHARACTER_WIDTH;
      for (byte i=0; i<CHARACTER_WIDTH; i++) {
        lcd.writeData(pgm_read_byte(font7x5 + position++));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Font.h:

```
#define CHARACTER_WIDTH 6
#define MAX_CHARACTERS_X 22
#define MAX_CHARACTERS_Y 8

const PROGMEM byte font7x5[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char NULL
  0x3E, 0x55, 0x51, 0x55, 0x3E, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x3E, 0x6B, 0x6F, 0x6B, 0x3E, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x0E, 0x1F, 0x3E, 0x1F, 0x0E, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x08, 0x1C, 0x3E, 0x1C, 0x08, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x98, 0x9B, 0xFF, 0x9B, 0x98, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x18, 0x5E, 0x7F, 0x5E, 0x18, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x7F, 0x77, 0x63, 0x77, 0x7F, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char     
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x30, 0x48, 0x48, 0x3E, 0x07, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x06, 0x29, 0x79, 0x29, 0x06, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x60, 0x7E, 0x06, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x49, 0x3E, 0x63, 0x3E, 0x49, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x08, 0x08, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x08, 0x1C, 0x3E, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x14, 0x22, 0x7F, 0x22, 0x14, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x06, 0x0F, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x08, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x08, 0x08, 0x78, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x04, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x08, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x1C, 0x08, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x08, 0x1C, 0x2A, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char  
  0x00, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char !
  0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char "
  0x74, 0x1C, 0x77, 0x1C, 0x17, 0x00,  // Code for char #
  0x24, 0x4A, 0xFF, 0x52, 0x24, 0x00,  // Code for char $
  0x43, 0x33, 0x08, 0x66, 0x61, 0x00,  // Code for char %
  0x36, 0x49, 0x55, 0x22, 0x50, 0x00,  // Code for char &
  0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char '
  0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char (
  0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char )
  0x00, 0x0A, 0x04, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char *
  0x00, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char +
  0x00, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ,
  0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char -
  0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char .
  0x00, 0x60, 0x1C, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char /
  0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E, 0x00,  // Code for char 0
  0x00, 0x42, 0x7F, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 1
  0x42, 0x61, 0x51, 0x49, 0x46, 0x00,  // Code for char 2
  0x22, 0x41, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, 0x00,  // Code for char 3
  0x1C, 0x13, 0x10, 0x78, 0x10, 0x00,  // Code for char 4
  0x4F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x31, 0x00,  // Code for char 5
  0x3E, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x32, 0x00,  // Code for char 6
  0x01, 0x01, 0x71, 0x09, 0x07, 0x00,  // Code for char 7
  0x36, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, 0x00,  // Code for char 8
  0x26, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x3E, 0x00,  // Code for char 9
  0x00, 0x00, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char :
  0x00, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ;
  0x00, 0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char <
  0x00, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char =
  0x00, 0x22, 0x14, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char >
  0x02, 0x01, 0x51, 0x09, 0x06, 0x00,  // Code for char ?
  0x3E, 0x5D, 0x5D, 0x51, 0x5E, 0x00,  // Code for char @
  0x7E, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x7E, 0x00,  // Code for char A
  0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36, 0x00,  // Code for char B
  0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22, 0x00,  // Code for char C
  0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22, 0x1C, 0x00,  // Code for char D
  0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x41, 0x00,  // Code for char E
  0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x01, 0x00,  // Code for char F
  0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x51, 0x32, 0x00,  // Code for char G
  0x7F, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x7F, 0x00,  // Code for char H
  0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char I
  0x00, 0x20, 0x40, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char J
  0x7F, 0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x41, 0x00,  // Code for char K
  0x7F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x00,  // Code for char L
  0x7F, 0x02, 0x0C, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x00,  // Code for char M
  0x7F, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x7F, 0x00,  // Code for char N
  0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E, 0x00,  // Code for char O
  0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06, 0x00,  // Code for char P
  0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x21, 0x5E, 0x00,  // Code for char Q
  0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x76, 0x00,  // Code for char R
  0x26, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x32, 0x00,  // Code for char S
  0x01, 0x01, 0x7F, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00,  // Code for char T
  0x3F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x3F, 0x00,  // Code for char U
  0x03, 0x1C, 0x60, 0x1C, 0x03, 0x00,  // Code for char V
  0x1F, 0x60, 0x18, 0x60, 0x1F, 0x00,  // Code for char W
  0x63, 0x14, 0x08, 0x14, 0x63, 0x00,  // Code for char X
  0x03, 0x04, 0x78, 0x04, 0x03, 0x00,  // Code for char Y
  0x61, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x43, 0x00,  // Code for char Z
  0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x00,  // Code for char [
  0x00, 0x03, 0x1C, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char BackSlash
  0x00, 0x41, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ]
  0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ^
  0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x00,  // Code for char _
  0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char `
  0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x7C, 0x00,  // Code for char a
  0x7F, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38, 0x00,  // Code for char b
  0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x28, 0x00,  // Code for char c
  0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x7F, 0x00,  // Code for char d
  0x38, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x58, 0x00,  // Code for char e
  0x00, 0x04, 0x7E, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char f
  0x18, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0x7C, 0x00,  // Code for char g
  0x7F, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78, 0x00,  // Code for char h
  0x00, 0x00, 0x7D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char i
  0x00, 0x40, 0x3D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char j
  0x7F, 0x20, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44, 0x00,  // Code for char k
  0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char l
  0x78, 0x04, 0x78, 0x04, 0x78, 0x00,  // Code for char m
  0x04, 0x78, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78, 0x00,  // Code for char n
  0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38, 0x00,  // Code for char o
  0xF8, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38, 0x00,  // Code for char p
  0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0xF8, 0x00,  // Code for char q
  0x00, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x00,  // Code for char r
  0x48, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x24, 0x00,  // Code for char s
  0x00, 0x04, 0x3F, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char t
  0x3C, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x7C, 0x00,  // Code for char u
  0x0C, 0x30, 0x40, 0x30, 0x0C, 0x00,  // Code for char v
  0x1C, 0x60, 0x1C, 0x60, 0x1C, 0x00,  // Code for char w
  0x44, 0x28, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44, 0x00,  // Code for char x
  0x44, 0x48, 0x30, 0x08, 0x04, 0x00,  // Code for char y
  0x44, 0x64, 0x54, 0x4C, 0x44, 0x00,  // Code for char z
  0x00, 0x08, 0x36, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char |
  0x00, 0x41, 0x36, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char }
  0x08, 0x04, 0x08, 0x08, 0x04, 0x00,  // Code for char ~
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x14, 0x3E, 0x55, 0x55, 0x41, 0x00,  // Code for char €
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ‚
  0x00, 0x84, 0x7E, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00,  // Code for char ƒ
  0xA0, 0x60, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x60, 0x00,  // Code for char „
  0x40, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00,  // Code for char …
  0x04, 0x04, 0xFF, 0x04, 0x04, 0x00,  // Code for char †
  0x24, 0x24, 0xFF, 0x24, 0x24, 0x00,  // Code for char ‡
  0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ˆ
  0x63, 0x13, 0x6C, 0x63, 0x60, 0x60,  // Code for char ‰
  0x48, 0x55, 0x56, 0x55, 0x24, 0x00,  // Code for char Š
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ‹
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Œ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ž
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ‘
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ’
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char “
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ”
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char •
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char –
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char —
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ˜
  0x01, 0x07, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03, 0x07,  // Code for char ™
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char š
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ›
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char œ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char 
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ž
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ÿ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char  
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¡
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¢
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char £
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¤
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¥
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¦
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char §
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¨
  0x7E, 0x81, 0xBD, 0xA5, 0x81, 0x7E,  // Code for char ©
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ª
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char «
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¬
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ­
  0x7E, 0x81, 0xBD, 0x9D, 0xA1, 0x7E,  // Code for char ®
  0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00,  // Code for char ¯
  0x00, 0x02, 0x05, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char °
  0x00, 0x48, 0x5C, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ±
  0x00, 0x09, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ²
  0x00, 0x09, 0x0D, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ³
  0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ´
  0xFC, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x3C, 0x00,  // Code for char µ
  0x06, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0x01, 0xFF, 0x01,  // Code for char ¶
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ·
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¸
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¹
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char º
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char »
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¼
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ½
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¾
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ¿
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char À
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Á
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Â
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ã
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ä
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Å
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Æ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ç
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char È
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char É
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ê
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ë
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ì
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Í
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Î
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ï
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ð
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ñ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ò
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ó
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ô
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Õ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ö
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ×
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ø
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ù
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ú
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Û
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ü
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Ý
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char Þ
  0xFE, 0x49, 0x49, 0x56, 0x20, 0x00,  // Code for char ß
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char à
  0xFE, 0x49, 0x49, 0x56, 0x20, 0x00,  // Code for char á
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char â
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ã
  0x38, 0x45, 0x44, 0x45, 0x7C, 0x00,  // Code for char ä
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char å
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char æ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ç
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char è
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char é
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ê
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ë
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ì
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char í
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char î
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ï
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ð
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ñ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ò
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ó
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ô
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char õ
  0x30, 0x4A, 0x48, 0x4A, 0x30, 0x00,  // Code for char ö
  0x08, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00,  // Code for char ÷
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ø
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ù
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ú
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char û
  0x38, 0x42, 0x40, 0x42, 0x78, 0x00,  // Code for char ü
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ý
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char þ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Code for char ÿ
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00   // Code for char 
};
```

Display.h

Can someone tell me whats wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, we need more information. What is TextDisplay.h and SPI.h? Where does it come from? Which display do you use?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Changed it according to your suggestions

Comment: After reading this code my next step would be to debug it. You can insert some `Serial.print()` into TextDisplay.cpp. But I'm not sure if the display will work.

Comment: It was a bug in a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download BugAVRgcc_Char.zip from http://tiny.systems/categorie/lcdProjekt/FragenAntworten.html and extract the new libraries